# How to answer "find the conditional distribution" question wrt rolls of a fair die

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have an answer to this question, but I'm not sure if my interpretation of the question is even right:

"In $n$ rolls of a fair die, let $X$ be the number of times 1 is rolled, and $Y$ the number of times 2 is rolled. Find the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y = y$."

My answer:
$$ P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X,Y)}{P(Y)}=\frac{P(X)P(Y)}{P(Y)}=P(X)
$$

Fairly confident this is right but I always get confused at "find the distribution" questions...I'm always unsure I'm being asked for a pdf/pmf (obviously not in this case, but in other questions with more numbers I guess) or something else.

Comment: Make a plot:  horizontal axis the possible outcomes ($1, 2, \ldots, 6$) and the vertical axis the probability of getting that value on a roll.  This may help you proceed...

Comment: and it should also be "given $n$", if I understood your question. But then X depends on Y, although the dependance decreases at large $n$'s

Comment: Remember that the joint probability is the product of the individual probabilities iff the events are independent. Your calculation says that the probability of getting a certain number of ones doesn’t depend on the number of twos that were rolled. Does that result seem sensible to you? As a concrete example, suppose that you roll once and you know that you rolled a two. What does that mean for the probability of having rolled a one?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork is that not just 1/6 for each in $(1, 2..., 6)$ ? My brain might be frozen here...

Comment: @amd Hmm I see so if n=5 and Y=2 then X<4